# Fixed Right Side Div scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I plan to have one right side navigation bar and content displayed on the left div. I tried searching for similar questions asked and tried to implement the solution but they do not seem to answer my questions. If someone could point me to the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it!! :)

UPDATE: http://jsfiddle.net/allenchuang/REWZ4/3/. Here is what i have so far, but when the window is resized and scrolling is required, the scroll bar appears right next to the orange div instead of being on the very right of the browser window. Is there anyway to get around it?

HTML

```
<body>
  <div id="page">
    <header id="sidebar">
        <h1>Sidebar (Fixed Width)</h1>

      <nav role="navigation">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Link One</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Link Two</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Link Three</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <article id="contentWrapper" role="main">
      <section id="content">
            <h1>Content (Fluid Width)</h1>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
          tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
          quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
          consequat.</p>
        <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum
          dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
          proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
          tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
          quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
          consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
          cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat
          non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
          tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
          quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
          consequat.</p>
        <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum
          dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
          proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
          tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
          quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
          consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
          cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat
          non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
          tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
          quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
          consequat.</p>
        <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum
          dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
          proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
          tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
          quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
          consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
          cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat
          non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </section>
    </article>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: What about this: http://stugreenham.com/demos/fluid-width-with-a-fixed-sidebar/ ? Having the sidebar on the right shouldn't be difficult at all.

Comment: @Robin I modified the code from the website you provided but when browsing in a small window the scroll appears on the left content. I want it to scroll for the whole window and still have the right side nav bar fixed. Any workarounds? See: http://jsfiddle.net/allenchuang/REWZ4/1/show/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.span9 {
float: left;
}

.span3 {
float: right;
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work. The scroll bar will appear right next to span9 instead of staying at the right of the browser. Any workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

Just give this code to the column which needs to have 100% height.

```
span
{
  position:absolute;
  height:100%;
}
```

Also note that the parent element should have a 100% height.
You can usually set that by:

```
html, body
{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```